# VBA: Inserting HTML tags to a specific HTML tag

Tags: html, css, excel, vba

I have this HTML tag in an excel table:
[image]

It needs to have different tags inserted in the `<h4>..</h4>` tags, to become this:

```
<!--opening div-->
<div id="ka-accordion" class="panel-group">

<!--this adds the collapse/expand all to the accordion-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4><button class="ka-accordion-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".panel-collapse">expand/collapse all</button></h4>
</div>
</div>

<!--Question 1-->

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4><button class="ka-accordion-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" data-parent="#ka-accordion">
      
    1st question, is what to do?
      
      </button></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-collapse-body">
        <p>
        
<p>Answer 1, body text</p>
<ol><li>some ordered list here included</li></ol>

        
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--You insert <h3>text heading<h/3> in between questions-->

 <!--Question 2-->
 
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4><button class="ka-accordion-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" data-parent="#ka-accordion">
      
Question no. 2.  from what, to law of gravity?
      
      </button></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-collapse-body">
        <p>
        
<p>some body text, to answer number 2</p>
<ol><li>some ordered list here</li></ol>

        
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

 <!--Question 3-->
 
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4><button class="ka-accordion-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" data-parent="#ka-accordion">
      
another inquiry, this is the 3rd?
      
      </button></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-collapse-body">
        <p>
        
<h3>a sub topic with body, responding to topic 3</h3>
<p>law of classroom article 1</p>

        
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


 <!--Question 4-->
 
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4><button class="ka-accordion-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" data-parent="#ka-accordion">
      
gravity b, question 4th h. collidron?
      
      </button></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-collapse-body">
        <p>
        
<p>law of classroom article 1, last answer to last question or topic</p>
<p>law of classroom article 1</p>

        
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So far, have coded this and getting error on (1) object not defined for the '&' in the string declaration. (2) And also don't know how to search the last `</p>` closing tag after the last `</h4>` and add the `F_Last` string after the closing paragraph tag:

```
Sub InsrtInTags()

Dim A_Start as String
Dim Aa As String
Dim B As String
Dim C As String
Dim D As String
Dim E As String
Dim F As String 
Dim F_Last As String
Dim Qs As String
Dim rng, cell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim pattern As String: pattern = "*<h4>*</h4>*"  ' Define the pattern
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
'Assign string values
A_Start = "<!--opening div-->" & vbCrLf & "<div id=""ka-accordion"" class=""panel-group"">" & vbCrLf & "<!--Question"
A = "</div></div></div><!--Question"
Aa = "-->" & vbCrLf & "<div class=""panel panel-default"">" & vbCrLf & "<div class=""panel-heading"">"
B = "<button class=""ka-accordion-btn"" data-toggle=""collapse"" data-target=""#collapse"""
C = "data-parent=""#ka-accordion"">"
D = "</button>"
E = "</div>" & vbCrLf & "<div id=""collapse"""
F = """ class=""panel-collapse collapse"">" & vbCrLf & "<div class=""panel-collapse-body"">"
F_Last = "</div>" & vbCrLf & "</div>" & vbCrLf & "</div>"


'loop through the range and search for h4 html tags

For Each cell In rng
    'Test for h4
    If (cell Like pattern = True) Then
    i = i + 1
    Qs = Mid(cell, InStr(1, cell, "<h4>", vbTextCompare) + 4, (InStr(1, cell, "</h4>", vbTextCompare)) - (InStr(1, cell, "<h4>", vbTextCompare) + 4))
    cell = A_Start & i & Aa & "<h4>" & B & i & C & Qs & D & "</h4>" & E & i & F 'uses the A_start which is a unique begining header tag
        If i > 1 Then
            cell = A & i & Aa & "<h4>" & B & i & C & Qs & D & "</h4>" & E & i & F 'uses generic header tag
        End If
        'add F_Last on last instance </p> of last </h4> no code yet
        </p> & F_Last
    
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

the questions or h4 header tags can be 4 to 20 or more.  That's why a counter is included and loop through.  Thanks!

Comment: **(1)** in VBA you need to specify the type for every variable separately. `Dim A_Start As String, Aa As String, B As String...`, else all but the last of the variables are of type `Variant`.  **(2)** Remove the `Set`, this is used in VBA to assign *Objects*, but a String is not an Object.

Comment: Updated to remove 'set' and declared strings individually.  In the loop line it says 'object doesn't support this property or method @FunThomas

Comment: What's the final reason for this? Why not parse with an HTML parser and add tags etc that way?

Comment: Hi @QHarr, the HTML parser is limited in terms that you need to manually insert the accordion script. This would enable it to be automatically inserted via VBA

Comment: You can still use vba to edit edit and insert nodes. I suppose the problem comes with <head> i.e. stuff before body etc but might be able to be wrapped in outer body tags which are later removed. Not ever tried that but wonder? There should be "" round tha last </p> And I guess it should be commented out until used in an assignment. Your error is because rng is set to a listobject. You cannot For Each over this singular ListObject. You want either a specific column or something like _For Each cell In rng.DataBodyRange_ . Make sure to declare all your vars e.g. A As String and use Long not Int

Comment: i.e. you want a range object to For Each over with _cell_ (as range) as collection member.